# How to specify spark version in Execution Launcher

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run my pyspark application in yarn client mode. Local spark version 2.3.0 with hadoop 2.6. Yarn cluster running on hadoop 2.6.0 but if has spark 1.6.0 and and 2.3.0 installed. When i specify 'spark.yarn.jars' previously downloaded in hdfs and run application. It trying to run Execution but fails with execption:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142
```

As far as i know if was moved after spark 1.6.0. So i think ExecutionLancher runs with spark-yarn.jar for spark 2.3.0(loaded from local spark) but with spark 1.6.0(installed on yarn host). Can't find information how to specify which spark version to use in yarn host.

Comment: Yarn host is actually CDH. I know it has problems with default old spark version. But there is a lot of tips how to install it, but not how to configure to use it.

Comment: At the end i found out that i upload not all required jars to spark. spark-core was missing and that's why logging error was appear